# Truncate file in linux with wget download active

Tags: linux, bash, download, wget, fallocate

i have background download with wget, i want, when the file is greater than 20mb, truncate the first 10mb of file, i have created this script:

```
if [ $filesize -ge $maxSize ]; then
            echo "Truncate.."
            kill -STOP $pidDwn
            fallocate -c -o 0 -l 10M $fileName
            kill -CONT $pidDwn
fi
```

this snippet recognize file size and truncate it for 10MB from beginning of file.

I stop wget progess, use fallocate for delete first 10MB, and after i resume the wget process for continue the download.
The problem is strange, if the file size is 20mb and i use fallocate WITHOUT resume the process wget, the file remains 10mb, but if i resume the wget process the file return to 20mb instantly and continue to increase with download.
If i use this command after resume the pid
`sed -i 1d $fileName` the file remains 10mb but not increase anymore with the download, seems like download is interrupted, but wget process still  alive if i use `ps aux` for see all process active

any idea for fix it?

Comment: While it's better to limit the scope of the questions on SO, I can say that the current question is an XY problem because of your comments on my answer. I can't even start making a guess on what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: i have solved by creating new file after 20mb, after some time i delete the oldfile, on the php page i use new file when i reach end of current file, the solution work, i want thank you for yuo time and patience, i mark you correct answer because it work in generale case, but in my case i need other. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> truncate the first 10mb of file

If server from which you are downloading said file support [Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206) gimmick then you might request [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) (part) of file.
First check if server support that feature do

```
wget --spider --server-response <url_to_resource>
```

if what was printed contain

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

then it does and you might request file starting from, say 100th byte using `Range` header that is

```
wget --header "Range: bytes=100-" <url_to_resource>
```

You should then get response with code 206 and download will start.